# Помогите с написанием программы на СИ

Tags: c

Прошу вашей помощи, т.к. совершенно не представляю, как это можно реализовать (мне кажется, не хватает данных/условий, т.е. как вообще можно ответить на поставленный вопрос даже без программы).

Вот условие:
Известны результаты (время в минутах), показанные автогонщиком — участником соревнований «Формула-1» на каждом этапе. Известно также, что на одном этапе он занял первое место и на одном — последнее. Верно ли, что этап, который он выиграл, был раньше этапа, на котором он занял последнее место?

Comment: Да, данных не хватает. Нет связи между временем и занятым местом.

Comment: Данных не хватает однозначно. Это становится очевидно, если представить, что каждый этап гонщик проехал за ровно одно и то же время (скажем, 60 минут), что по условию является вполне допустимым вариантом входных данных.

Comment: Задача глупая. Но мне кажется, что хотели спросить `верно ли, что минимальный элемент массива стоит раньше максимального?` При этом не учитывается, что возможна ситуация, когда для занятия первого места понадобилось полтора часа, а последнего - час (погода была лучше)

Comment: @0andriy, это задача из сборника Златопольского, к которой нужно написать программу.